# How to screen lock/unlock xubuntu over ssh

Tags: xubuntu, lock

I'm running the latest Xubuntu, and I'd like to be able to lock the main screen from a remote ssh session, and then also unlock it.

I know I can lock from the console using xflock4 - I presume there must be some way to make that work over ssh.  But I can't work out how to unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `screen` possesses the ability to lock a screen session.

Simply start a GNU screen by running:

```
$ screen
```

Then type `Ctrl-a Ctrl-x`. You should get something like:

```
Screen used by bear <bear> on bones.
Password:
```